# Can vector<T>::clear throw?

Tags: c++, exception, vector

Is there any chance for a call to `std::vector<T>::clear()` to throw an exception?

Comment: Excellent question, revealing that many people do not know the correct answer!

Comment: @VJo: I didn't get a chance to respond before you deleted your answer. "That makes the exception to be thrown from only one object": How so?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**No.**

> `[2003: 21.2.1/11 | n3290: 21.2.1/10]:` Unless otherwise specified
>   (see 23.2.4.1, 23.2.5.1, 23.3.3.4, and 23.3.6.5) all container types
>   defined in this Clause meet the following additional requirements:
>   [..] — **no `erase()`, `clear()`, `pop_back()` or `pop_front()`
>   function throws an exception**. [..]

---

#### What happens if my element type destructor throws?

In C++11, `std::vector<T>::clear()` is marked `noexcept` (`[n3290: 23.3.6/1]`).

Any exceptions falling out of `~T` could be caught by the implementation, so that `clear()` itself may not throw anything. If they're not, and it does, the exception is "unexpected" and terminates the process rather than propagating:

```
struct T {
   ~T() { throw "lol"; }
};

int main() {
   try {
      vector<T> v{T()};
      v.clear();
   }
   catch (...) {
      cout << "caught";
   }
}

// Output: "terminated by exception: lol" (GCC 4.7.0 20111108)
```

> `[n3290: 15.5.1]:` In some situations exception handling must be
>   abandoned for less subtle error handling techniques. [..] — when the
>   search for a handler (15.3) encounters the outermost block of a
>   function with a *no-except-specification* that does not allow the
>   exception (15.4) [..]

Comment: I think one of the requirements for an element type instantiating a `vector` is that its destructor doesn't throw.  If you violate the requirements, the behavior is undefined, so there is no need for an exception from `~T()` to be caught by the implementation.

Comment: @James: Fair enough. I guess `.clear` is `noexcept` to add that extra layer of diagnostic safety then.

Comment: @James: I just revisited your comment and understood it properly at last. My "must catch" was misplaced, and not meant in that way. :)

Answer (score 5):

Yes, if the destructor of `T` throws, otherwise no.

*Update:*
seems i was dead wrong; it just crashes in that case

Comment: so I'd say that as long as I'm using std:: types there will be no throw (because they do not throw in dtors), am I right?

Answer (score -2):

Yes and No

Yes:

`clear` eventually calls `delete[]` operator, which involves calling destructors of all the objects an the array (if they have one) and `free` the memory.

Destructors may eventually throw an exception.

Memory freeing may also fail in abrnormal cases (such as heap corruption or etc.)

No:

Throwing exceptions is destructors is criticized and mostly doesn't happen (at least in the standard libraries). Besides the fact that exception thrown from a destructor during the stack unwinding (caused by another exception) may not be handled, there is a logical problem with exceptions in destructors.

Error in freeing memory usually caused by heap corruption or other unrecoverable problem. Anyway the program's fate is to die, no matter if there'll be exception or not

Comment: This is incorrect.  `clear` (and in fact no function of `std::vector`) will never call `delete[]`.

Comment: @ James Kanze: Yes, you're right, vectors don't free the memory so quickly